# type annotation is required on a value parameter / jetpackcompose

Tags: android-studio, annotations, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a composable function in android studio which has a composable function as a parameter which returns nothing. I am following the steps from a Udemy course. Here is the image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klbYa.png)

Trying to create a composable function that accepts an argument of composable which returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a space between `@Composable` and parentheses:

```kotlin
// this is a variable of functional type "() -> Unit" with @Composable annotation
val content: @Composable () -> Unit,

// this is a call to constructor of @Composable annotation class and
// some invalid characters after it: "-> Unit"
val content: @Composable()-> Unit,
```